# How to obtain citation metrics for a low-profile journal that is not indexed in major journal databases?

Tags: bibliometrics

I am interested in generating citation-metrics for [The journal of the British Association for the Study of Religions](http://jbasr.com/basr/diskus/index.html) using Google Scholar or such tools. (The journal is not indexed in almost any selective database, compounding my woes.)

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but I just want to point out that you can to some extent retrieve citations from, for instance, Web of Science (WoS) to journals that are not covered by the citation index per se. For instance, by doing a "Cited reference search". There you will find citations to documents, based on the citation information given in reference list of WoS publications, irrespective of whether the "target" publications (the ones receiving the citations) are covered by WoS.

For instance, when searching for "BRIT ASS STUDY RELIG" (a generalization of "The journal of the British Association for the Study of Religions", which seems to be found in WoS) as "Cited work" I find a ten citations in total to the journal.

This is probably not completely what you are after, but might be useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Google Scholar* and search for `source:"JOURNAL NAME"`.

---

In your case, however, [source:"Journal of the British Association for the Study of Religions"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=source%3A%22Journal%20of%20the%20British%20Association%20for%20the%20Study%20of%20Religions%22) yields **0** results.

Using the abbreviation [source:"BASR"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=source%3A%22BASR%22) does lead to more useful results (**37** in total), albeit you need to disambiguate the Journal of the BASR (DISKUS) from other publication outlets from BASR.

The most fruitful query for your purposes seems to be [source:"DISKUS"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=source%3A%22DISKUS%22); it yields **256** results.

Answer (score -4):

To gain citations for the articles published within JBASR, first you must get read. 
Have both the authors and the journal board do their PR thing. Have them use all the social media, Twitter, LinkedIn and such; use all the sites like Google Scholar, ResearchGate, Academia.edu, Mendeley etc. - have all the authors make profiles there and have them make their papers available. Ask authors to refer to both articles within JBASR as well as in priority journals. Use the editorial in every issue to properly cite certain articles within that issue and previous issues.
Think about what it is exactly that you mean to accomplish.

Comment: I read the question as asking about how to find out how many citations there are, etc., rather than how to get more citations.